# distance function of Google AppEngine Search API is behaving unconsistantly

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

```
    String loc_expr = "distance(location, geopoint(" + userLatitude + ", " + userLongitude + "))";

    // Build the SortOptions
    SortOptions sortOptions = SortOptions.newBuilder()
            .addSortExpression(SortExpression.newBuilder().setExpression(loc_expr).setDirection(SortExpression.SortDirection.ASCENDING).setDefaultValueNumeric(0))
            .setLimit(200).build();

    // Build the QueryOptions
    QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder().addExpressionToReturn(FieldExpression.newBuilder().setExpression(loc_expr).setName("distance")).setLimit(limit)
            .setCursor(cursor).setSortOptions(sortOptions).build();

    String queryString = loc_expr + " < " + searchRadius * 1000;

    // Build the Query and run the search
    Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build(queryString);

    IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("restaurants").build();
    Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);

    Results<ScoredDocument> result = index.search(query);
    if (result.getNumberFound() > 0) {
        Collection<ScoredDocument> coll = result.getResults();

        for (ScoredDocument sd : coll) {
            Key<Restaurant> key = Key.create(String.valueOf(sd.getId()));
            Restaurant rest = ofy().load().key(key).now();

            Field f = sd.getExpressions().get(0);
            log.info("distance in meter : " + f.getNumber());
        }
    }
```

I am using the above mentioned code to get restaurants in nearby area. Following are my observation :-

Case 1: searchRadius = 0.5 km  ---  Maximum value of distance = 0.9 km

Case 2: searchRadius = 1 km ---  maximum value of distance = 1.8 km

Case 3: searchRadius = 2 km ---  maximum value of distance = 2.8 km

Case 4: searchRadius = 3 km ---  maximum value of distance = 4.8 km

Why am I getting value of distance more the radius specified?

**Note** :- I am not calculating distance by my own. Distance is being returned by search API.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8824).

Until Google fix it, you have to filter the results in your code